# Github action for pull request not running

Tags: github, github-actions

Github actions on pull request were working yesterday. Today they are not running.

`.github/workflows/pull_request.yml` looks like

```
name: Pull Request

on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
      - '.github/**'

jobs:
  black_and_flake8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout code"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "Lint project"
        uses: ./.github/actions/lint_project

  test_common:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Checkout code"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "Test common"
        uses: ./.github/actions/test_common

  test_dags:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout code"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "Test dags"
        uses: ./.github/actions/test_dags

[etc there are a lot of jobs for different parts of this repo]
```

For example, `./github/actions/test_dags` has a single `action.yml` file inside that looks like this

```
name: "test_dags"
description: "Tests for code that lives in /dags"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Run pytest
      working-directory: dags
      run: |
        docker build -t dagtest -f Dockerfile.airflow_dags_test . 
        docker run --name=dagtestimage dagtest
        docker cp dagtestimage:/tmp/htmlcov .
      shell: bash

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: dags_htmlcov
        path: /home/runner/work/processing/processing/dags/htmlcov/
```

Putting aside that there may be a smarter way to run these tests, why are no actions being fired at all when I make a pull request now?  It happily ran all my checks yesterday. Nothing has merged into main related to github actions- just some pytest stuff for one of the modules, and that ran the checks.

My PR is changing the dockerfile referenced in the action above, updating requirements.txt, and to debug I changed a python file (in case those file types were magically excluded).

The GUI for the PR doesn't show any checks. Nothing new shows up in the Actions tab.

How do I figure out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out github is having an issue - https://www.githubstatus.com/ said everything was green when I posted this, but it has since updated to

> Incident with GitHub Actions, API Requests, Codespaces, Git Operations, GitHub Packages, and GitHub Pages